# Is it possible to SSH every minute for 24/7?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm running a cronjob every minute to SSH to a different Linux based device to execute some bash commands to retrieve some data. I am wondering whether if this would cause any issue?
Because after awhile, I am getting some error by manually executing SSH command to the device

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer.

Because this device is not configure by me, I am not sure the error is
caused by the frequent SSH connection from my device.

Is it possible to run it 24/7 without closing?

Comment: How about asking the device/server's maintainer about what their logs say?

Comment: Look at using the `ControlMaster` feature to reuse a single, authenticated connection across sessions, rather than trying to establish a brand new session every minute. Also, consider running a single long-lived script (via your system's `initd` or equivalent) that simply sends back data once a minute.

Comment: hi @Roadowl , I could try, but I believe it is a networking device which I wonder he is able to provide me the logs, the firmware might be customized

Comment: hi @chepner, the reason to connect every minute was I wanted to have the data (wrote in a file) to POST to my database server (outside of network) by CURL. To make sure it was not too outdated, I would like to have it updated every minute. I am assuming that the other device does not have many storage for me to create files on it and only POST it to the device, so I am running a tee command to store it to my device then only CURL to POST it...Still thinking how could I implement one session that is able to update every minute